# How does validation work in database-first dbContext (EF4.3.1 & MVC3)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation, dbcontext

How does validation work in database-first `DbContext` (EF4.3.1 & MVC3)?

I'm doing this (yes, it's VB):

```
If ModelState.IsValid Then
    db.SaveChanges()
```

But the `SaveChanges` throws `DbEntityValidationException` with the following message:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

I expect it to return the view again with the appropriate validation messages, but clearly I'm missing something because I don't know why it should work that way!  You would expect Google to help, but most examples seem to be code-first.

This is database first, so the model has been generated. I would expected the validation constraints to be generated too (at least simple ones like NOT NULL in SQL Server) , but that doesn't seem to work.

Oddly, some fields are working as expected and others aren't.

For example, I have a non-nullable text field in the database. It appears as non-nullable in the EF designer and in the generated code. But when I submit it, I get the exception instead of returning the form with the field highlighted.

On the other hand, I have a date field that is non-nullable. It is checked prior to trying to update the database, and the form is presented again with the field highlighted for correction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't ModelState.IsValid work properly for foreign key constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409766/why-doesnt-modelstate-isvalid-work-properly-for-foreign-key-constraint)